# React native and web version control

Tags: git, version-control, reactjs

React Native lets me reuse large chunks of code from the react web application in the mobile app. In fact, only the components differ, while the data layer stays the same.

I want to keep the data layer in sync in two git source controlled projects. What are some good ways to do this? Does it change the webpack build flow at all?